# Jquery .get function not reading txt file

Tags: jquery, get

I'm not sure why this is happening. The below function is executing correctly. The path file is correct. I've tried to add "text" after, and json etc. But the data is empty??? I'm at my wits end, I'm not sure why this happening. Please help

```
var str = "";
$.get(
   "steps.txt",
    function(data){
        str = data;
    }, 
    "text"
);
```

Comment: How are you determining that the data is empty?

Comment: I am doing console.log(str) but it gives nothing. The file definitely has data in it, but I'm ripping my hair out over this. I can't seem to see why it's wrong.

Comment: Where are you doing the console.log at?  Remember that ajax requests are asynchronous.

Comment: just after the call

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous.  It will not have finished, or probably even started, by the time your console log immediately after it is invoked.  You can stick your console.log inside the ajax callback method and log it there.

Comment: wow, that worked, but then how do I get the data out and use it in the rest of my file. Because it's not working outside.

Comment: Read the duplicate.

Comment: sorry, I'm a bit new to this. How do I do that?